# Google news not showing correct teaser

Tags: google-news

An example for my site is this:

[image]

We have a schema in place, a title, headline etc but we get the text:

```
IQ publishes a regular magazine...
```

The thing is, this appears near the end of the page in the middle of a paragraph.

Why is it showing this instead of the actual teaser?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `max-snippet:-1` on your story pages, try removing that or changing it to something larger.